# Using OMP to calculate fuel

Tags: c, openmpi

So this is just a basic program that reads values from a file and then calculates for each value the amount of fuel it would take. f = (m/4)-3. I have it working but I feel I would have a better timing if more threads could be doing some of these things at the same time.
Currently without that critical section, I am getting incorrect or changing results. I am wondering if theres a way I can reduce the amount in the critical section or otherwise optimize this section more. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
#pragma omp parallel for  reduction(+:fuelUnits) schedule(dynamic) 
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            i = arr[j];
            //printf("i = %d\n", i);

            mass += i;
            printf("i = %d\n", i);
            fuel2 = fuel(i);
        }
            fuelUnits += fuel2;
            printf("fuel is %d\n", fuel2);
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove `mass+=i`? Does it need to be included in your reduction operation: (ex: `reduction(+:fuelUnits, mass)`?

This should work without the critical section:

```
// somewhere globally:
int fuelUnits = 0;

// your fuel function here:
int fuel(int m) {
 return (m/4)-3 
}


-- snip --
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:fuelUnits) schedule(dynamic)
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)) {
    int i = arr[j];
    fuelUnits += fuel(i);
}
```